# Early access to the underlying HttpWebRequest before a POST with RestSharp

Tags: tfs, httpwebrequest, restsharp

I'd like to use RestSharp to make a POST to a TFS server, but I need to do some fairly sophisticated manipulations on the web request before the call is made.

To that end, I need access to the underlying HttpWebRequest to make a "Prepare" style call.

Is that possible with RestSharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestSharp doesn't expose HttpWebRequest directly so you're probably best served writing your own custom wrapper.

Comment: Thanks John, it's a shame the abstraction can't be made to leak, because otherwise it does a lot of what i want.

Comment: You can swap out IHttp if needed.